# Radio buttons and label to display in same line

Tags: html, css

Why my labels and radio buttons won't stay in the same line, what can I do ?

Here is my form:

```
<form name="submit" id="submit" action="#" method="post">
    <?php echo form_hidden('what', 'item-'.$identifier);?>

    <label for="one">First Item</label>
    <input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="1" />

    <label for="two">Second Item</label>
    <input type="radio" id="two" name="first_item" value="2" />
    <input class="submit_form" name="submit" type="submit" value="Choose" tabindex="4" />
</form>
```

Comment: Could you show the whole page and the corresponding css? If you put only the snippet you provided in the body of an HTML page everything will be on the same line so there must be some css rule that prevents this.

Comment: Which XHTML schema are you using?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I have a large css files to be posting here wouldn't be a good idea, what should I look for inside of the(have multiple style sheets) or how can I style this one seperatly?

Comment: @eyazici <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: Try on CSS 

    `input[type=radio], .radio {
      display: inline;
    }`

For IE, you'll have to add on `<input class="radio" />` since IE doesn't follow the other CSS notion.

Comment: try resizing the browser window to full screen ?

Comment: Try installing firebug and using the "Inspect" function to list the CSS rules that apply to your elements.

Comment: Obviously I’m four years late doing this, but here’s your form, and your radio buttons and labels are on the same line: http://jsfiddle.net/BJU4f/ Please provide code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you use the HTML structure I lay out [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350152/documentation-on-fieldset-label-tags-instead-of-using-tables/2350481#2350481) you can simply float your label and input to the left and adjust padding/margin until things are lined up.

And yes, you'll want to make your radio button have a class name for old IE. And to have *all* of them on the same line, according to the markup I linked to above, it would be like so:

```css
fieldset {
      overflow: hidden
    }
    
    .some-class {
      float: left;
      clear: none;
    }
    
    label {
      float: left;
      clear: none;
      display: block;
      padding: 0px 1em 0px 8px;
    }
    
    input[type=radio],
    input.radio {
      float: left;
      clear: none;
      margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
    }
```

```html
<fieldset>
      <div class="some-class">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="x" value="y" id="y" />
        <label for="y">Thing 1</label>
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="x" value="z" id="z" />
        <label for="z">Thing 2</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: (I'd suggest actually switching around, with labels after the radio buttons, but that's your call.)

Comment: <label for="x">Thing 1</label> should be <label for="y">Thing 1</label>

Comment: @D_N, can you please fix the label for attribute, I tried but my edit was less than 6 chars so I could not submit.

Comment: Disappeared for a while. Thanks for fixing that.

Comment: @animuson has a better solution that nests the input inside the label. Scroll down and support that one instead!

`<label for="one">
<input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="1" />
First Item
</label>`

Comment: @JosephCho Nesting the input inside the label is fine, but still needs some CSS to stay on the same line in all contexts. People should use what their use case requires.

Comment: Nice its working, but 'some-class' working all other label inside another div tag.

Answer (score 75):

What I've always done is just wrap the radio button inside the label...

```
<label for="one">
<input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="1" />
First Item
</label>
```

Something like that, has always worked for me.

Comment: That won't work by itself, there's nothing stopping the words inside the label from being split on different lines. You'd need to make the label display:block or white-space:nowrap.  Also, I'm not sure it's semantically correct to have the input inside the label.

Comment: It is valid to have input wrapped by label element. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element

Comment: The benefit of having the input wrapped by the label is that it makes the text clickable to activate the radio button instead of the user having to click directly on the radio, which is useful for people who are using mobile devices and don't have the pinpoint click accuracy you'd get from a mouse pointer.

Answer (score 11):

you might have a **width** specified for your **input** tags somewhere in your **css**.

add a `class="radio"` to your radio boxes and an `input.radio {width: auto;}` to your css.

Comment: The better way to do this would be to use the input type selector in your css instead of adding a new class. You can simply add `input:radio { /* styles here */ }` or `input[type="radio"] { /* styles here */ }`to your css. There's no need to use a separate class to specify the style rules when you are applying them too all elements that are a radio input.

Answer (score 9):

I always avoid using `float:left` but instead I use `display: inline`

```css
.wrapper-class input[type="radio"] {
  width: 15px;
}

.wrapper-class label {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-class">
  <input type="radio" id="radio1">
  <label for="radio1">Test Radio</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Put them both to `display:inline`.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm. By default, `<label>` is `display: inline;` and `<input>` is (roughly, at least) `display: inline-block;`, so they should both be on the same line. See http://jsfiddle.net/BJU4f/

Perhaps a stylesheet is setting `label` or `input` to `display: block`?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming the problem is that they are wrapping onto separate lines when the window is too narrow.  As others have pointed out, by default the label and input should be "display:inline;", so unless you have other style rules that are changing this, they should render on the same line if there is room.

Without changing the markup, there will be no way to fix this using only CSS.

The simplest way to fix it would be to wrap the radio button and label in a block element, such as a `p` or a `div`, and then prevent that from wrapping by using `white-space:nowrap`.  For example:

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;">
  <label for="one">First Item</label>
  <input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**
Used table to align the radio and text in one line

> 

```html
<div >
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Do you want to add new server ?</strong></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="addServer" id="serverYes" value="1"></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="addServer" id="serverNo" value="1"></td>
        <td>No</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**

Comment: Please add a brief explanation of what you did, so that the author may better understand your solution

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce your problem in Google Chrome 4.0, IE8, or Firefox 3.5 using that code. The label and radio button stayed on the same line.

Try putting them both inside a `<p>` tag, or set the radio button to be inline like The Elite Gentleman suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code and works just fine:

```
input[type="checkbox"], 
input[type="radio"],
input.radio,
input.checkbox {
    vertical-align:text-top;
    width:13px;
    height:13px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:2px;
}
```

You may want to readjust top value (depends on your `line-height`). If you don't want IE6 compatibility, you just need to put this code into your page. Otherwise, you will must add extra class to your inputs (you can use jQuery - or any other library - for that tho ;) )

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the label and input are wrapping to two lines when the window is too narrow, remove the whitespace between them; e.g.:

```
<label for="one">First Item</label>
<input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="1" />
```

If you need space between the elements, use non-breaking spaces (`&amp;` `nbsp;`) or CSS.

Answer (score 0):

My answer from a different post on the same subject should help you [zend form for multicheckbox remove input from labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229437/zend-form-for-multicheckbox-remove-input-from-labels/6266429#6266429)

Answer (score 0):

Note: Traditionally the use of the label tag is for menus. eg:

```
<menu>
<label>Option 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="opt1">

<label>Option 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="opt2">

<label>Option 3</label>
<input type="radio" id="opt3">  
</menu>
```

Comment: 1. No it’s not — [it’s for labelling form elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sec-forms.html#the-label-element), whether in a menu or not. 2. You’re meant to specify which form element the label describes, by putting the form element’s `id` as the value of the `for` attribute on the `<label>` element. Your example misses that out.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the similar issue of keeping all radio buttons on the same line. After trying all the things I could, nothing worked for me except the following. What I mean is simply using table resolved the issue allowing radio buttons to appear in the same line.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButton("p_sortForPatch", "byName", new { @checked = "checked", @class = "radio" }) By Name
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButton("p_sortForPatch", "byDate", new { @class = "radio" }) By Date
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fieldset {
  overflow: hidden
}

.class {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}

label {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  display:initial;
}

input[type=radio],input.radio {
  float: left;
  clear: both;     
}
```