# abnormal spacing for radio input

Tags: html, css

Ok so I've tried several previous SO answers and still no luck

[Radio buttons and label to display in same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306117/radio-buttons-and-label-to-display-in-same-line)

[Documentation on <FIELDSET> <LABEL> tags instead of using TABLE's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350152/documentation-on-fieldset-label-tags-instead-of-using-tables/2350481#2350481)

[Keep radio buttons with their labels on line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714414/keep-radio-buttons-with-their-labels-on-line-breaks)

There is something weird going on that's forcing some abnormal behavior for my radio. Would appreciate some help/guidance as to what I can do to fix this! Any help is appreciated.

Live Demo: http://iam.colum.edu/students/jordan.max/web-template(2)/index.html

main.html

```
<div id="container">

    <form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
        <p class="textHeader"><strong> First Name </strong></p>
        <input name="firstname" type="text" oninvalid="invalidFName(this);" oninput="invalidFName(this);" placeholder="First Name" required />

        <p class="textHeader"><strong> Last Name </strong></p>
        <p> </p>
        <input id="lastName" type="text" oninvalid="invalidLName(this);" oninput="invalidLName(this);" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required />

        <p class="textHeader"><strong> Email </strong></p>
        <input id="emailaddress" type="email" oninvalid="invalidEmail(this);" name="emailaddress" placeholder="anything@example.com"  required />

        <fieldset>
            <div class="some-class">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" name="x" value="y" id="y" />
                <label for="y">Thing 1</label>
                <input type="radio" class="radio" name="x" value="z" id="z" />
                <label for="z">Thing 2</label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />

    </form>

</div>
```

CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following in your stylesheet:

```
#container input, #container select, #container textarea {
    width: 450px;
    border: 1px solid #CEE1E8;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

The `width: 450px;` is throwing out the layout of your radio field. You could try adding something like this after that statement to override it for radios:

```
#container input[type=radio] {
    width: auto;
}
```