# Get labels and Radiobuttons all on 1 line:

Tags: css, radio-button, alignment, label

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Radio buttons and label to display in same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306117/radio-buttons-and-label-to-display-in-same-line)

I have 3 labels and radiobuttons that i want to put on 1 line:

What i get now is this:

```
Spoortoegang
Uit
radiobutton
Aan
radiobutton
```

What i want is:

```
Spoortoegang Uit radiobutton Aan radiobutton
```

My code for this is:

```
<div ><p>Spoortoegang</p><label for="no">Uit;<input dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton"   id="valSR" name="group1" checked="checked" onchange='POI(this);' value="Show" type="radio"/>    </label>
<label for="yes">Aan;<input dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" id="valSlope" name="group1"   value="Hide" onchange='POI(this)' type="radio"/></label></div>
```

Comment: That HTML will not give that result without CSS being applied to change the default rendering.

Comment: You have a set of fields, you should use a `fieldset` with a `legend`, not a `div` with a `p`.

Answer (score 0):

add "float: left" in css for all elements

Comment: Why use float? There's no sign that any block rendering is needed, so float is unnecessarily fiddly (especially if elements end up being different heights)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS for positioning DOM elements. As you want all elements to be inline:

```
p, label, input { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting it in a paragraph enclose it in a span like

```
<div ><span>Spoortoegang</span><div >
```