# Multiple radio buttons and corresponding labels display in the same line within a nested div

Tags: html, css

I looked into this post since it's exactly what I am trying to achieve: [Radio Button and Label to display in same line.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2306117/2061309)

Yet the struggle continues... Here's the layout I have (first 3 columns) and I expect to have (last two columns). Please ignore the outline boxes. Those were drawn just to mark the div.

I have two to three radio buttons that needs to be in the same line, as per the image shown below. These radio buttons their title should be within one div and nested inside a main div that contains the radio buttons, and the other html selector (*e.g. Capacity*) I tried giving enough width to this `div`, so radio buttons can sit horizontally in one line. But it doesn't work.

[image]

**[jsFiddle for html and css.](https://jsfiddle.net/ud3qL6co/)**

---

After removing `float:left`, `width`, `height` from said classes. As you see the Select button no longer aligns.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Comment the css - `height` and `width` of `#bookingForm input`, `#bookingForm textarea`

Comment: the width can't be removed from this bookingform input area. Because it affect the text input controls. If I remove it here, where else can I manage it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float: left;` from `.fl1 em`

And remove `width` and `height` from `#bookingForm input, #bookingForm textarea` will solve your issue.

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ud3qL6co/3/)

Comment: The label of radio buttons have a class called `tmRadio`. Although this seems to align the radio buttons, it affects the Capacity `select button`. Since the class for all divs the same, it shouldn't really get affected. Unless there's a `margin-bottom` to be fixed for class `tmRadio`.

Comment: @aspiring remove `float: left;` from `.fl1 em +div`. Check https://jsfiddle.net/ud3qL6co/4/.

Comment: @aspiring ohh ok i got it `.tmRadio {
    height: 30px;
}` will solved issue.  Check https://jsfiddle.net/ud3qL6co/5/

Comment: Nope, `height` will not work since background color has to be provided and the height must be same size as other grayish controls. So as guessed `margin-bottom` and `padding` did the trick for this alignment.

Comment: Assuming I have a div with entire button group styled and aligned into one line. How can I incorporate that into this `fl1 fl2` class? Because changing classes here and there seems less standard for maintaining the css file.

Comment: It is because  to class `.tmSelect.auto, .tmSelect2.auto`  you already given height.

Comment: You can also give `padding-bottom: 10px;` to `.tmRadio ` instead of height

Comment: It will effect because radio button have less width. If you trying to change in f1 f2 class then it will effect to all.

Comment: removing `width` from the booking form input is not the right move here. It is clearly messing up with the all the other text input controls. How else would you approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove CSS height and width property from this style.

```
#bookingForm input, #bookingForm textarea{ }
```