# Align Radio-Buttons and its Labels

Tags: html, css

I am getting crazy right now since i try to style my radio buttons for hours now and i cant reach my goal (im completely new to the world of css).

What i want to do is simple:

I want three big radiobuttons underneath each other centered in my div with labels vertically aligned to the buttons. something similar to this:

[image]

I have the following html:

```
<div class="answers">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="answers" value="male" /> All
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="answers" value="female" /> Name
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="answers" value="male" /> Vendor No.
    </label>
</div>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

I want much bigger buttons and much bigger text. i want the text to be to the right of the buttom with a little padding. i want all radio buttons to be centered. I tried many things but everything was just looking weird. Pls help me... i am beginning to hate css....

Comment: Post your CSS too please.

Comment: i deleted my whole css because of madness!

Comment: Well, the layout depends on the CSS, which you haven't posted, but I'm betting that your `input` is styled as `display:block;`

Comment: for the result i posted above i did not use any cs. the div isnt styled so arent the label and the input. its the standard result i get from just using the html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306117/radio-buttons-and-label-to-display-in-same-line

Comment: label{    display:block;  }    http://plnkr.co/edit/7AGJsjw6u0V7XyuI7T8i?p=preview

Comment: Don't keep text open like that. wrap in a span. and use this code. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/6g5gLjy7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this CSS:

```
.answers label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
}
.answers {
  width: 100%;
}
.answers input[type="radio"] {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 30px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/uqyfbjsb/

Comment: with that css the text is still under the radio buttons.

Comment: @Mulgard updated my answer. Which browser are you using ?

Comment: google chrome: if i use your code it does not look like in your jsfiddle. the text is not vertically aligned to the radio buttons

Comment: @Mulgard this can be due to the width of your anwers div. I've updated my answer with a class to set a width (but probably not). You've said you don't have any CSS right ? can you post your full HTML ? (I've just tried on chrome using a local file, and it's looks the same as the fiddle)

Comment: pls add `.answers input[type="radio"] {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}` to your js fiddle and see what happens.

Comment: @Mulgard updated the answer to include your input width correctly

Answer (score 2):

The only reason to happen this is to have `display: block` somewhere in your css to radios:

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="answers">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="answers" value="male" />All
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="answers" value="female" />Name
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="answers" value="male" />Vendor No.
  </label>
</div>
```

You can add `display: block` to second label using `nth-child`:

```css
label:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="answers">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="answers" value="male" />All
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="answers" value="female" />Name
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="answers" value="male" />Vendor No.
  </label>
</div>
```

**References**

[nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)

Comment: no. i have no css at all for the div, the label and the input!

Comment: Do you use external css files? Like bootstrap?

Comment: no. i have pure html without any css now. its just a single file.

Comment: Check my suggest solution.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/6b888vp8/2/

Add display: block to the label in the answers div, and float left to the inputs. HTML has changed too

```
.answers label {
    display: block
}

.answers input[type="radio"] {
    float: left;
}

<div class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="answers" value="male" /><label>All</label>
    <input type="radio" name="answers" value="female" /><label>Name</label>
    <input type="radio" name="answers" value="male" /><label>Vendor No.</label>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont want all radio buttons to be on one line!

Comment: but thats again not what i want. the text is not vertically centered to the radio buttons.... thats the reason why i hate css...

Comment: Updated my fiddle, is that what you want?

Comment: its quite good but if i increas the font-size of the label text it isnt vertically aligned with the radio button.

Answer (score -1):

This one worked for me:

```css
 input[type="radio"]{
    width: 50px !important;
 }
```

Try it out and check if it works for you as well.

Comment: `!important` is bad practice and should not be used by web developers unless absolutely necessary (or perhaps never, depending on who you ask). It exists for user stylesheets so that users may adjust the styling of a website (for example to aid accessibility).