# How do I specify the text to display next to a radio button in Scala.js?

Tags: scala.js, scalatags

I have two radio buttons, one for SBT and one for Gradle.  How do I specify the text for the buttons in Scala.js?  My code looks like this:

```scala
lazy val toolChoice = fieldset(
      legend("Build Tool"),
      input(`type`:="radio", name:="tool", value:="sbt", "SBT"),
      input(`type`:="radio", name:="tool", value:="gradle", "Gradle")
).render
```

I see the buttons, but not the text.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio buttons do not have text per se. You need to have a sibling element to display the text. Ideally a `<label>`, so that it is clickable. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/2350782/1829647

In Scalatags, I guess it would look like this:

```scala
lazy val toolChoice = fieldset(
    legend("Build Tool"),
    input(`type`:="radio", name:="tool", value:="sbt", id:="toolsbt"),
    label(`for`:="toolsbt", "sbt"),
    input(`type`:="radio", name:="tool", value:="gradle", id:="toolgradle"),
    label(`for`:="toolgradle", "Gradle")
).render
```

Comment: I usually do it as `label(input(...), "text")`, but yeah -- you want a label associated with the input...

Comment: This looks promising except id="toolsbt" is coming up "reassignment to val", pointing at id.

Comment: @sjrd: I got it working.  Change id= to id:= above and I'll accept your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo, but useful because of the error message it generated.  I'm always on the lookout for patterns between error messages and solutions.