# Keep radio button and label on the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm having a CSS issue where the radio button and label are appearing on different lines if the label spans multiple lines. Here is an example:

```
() Option A
() Option B
()
  Option C is really long so it
  will span two lines
() Option D
```

See how the long lines are breaking after the radio option? The long label-body should span two lines, but it should be inline with the radio option such as:

```
() Option C is really long so it
   will span two lines
```

Here's my CSS

```
input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 0px; }
label > .label-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  font-weight: normal; }
```

And finally the HTML

```
<label>
  <input type="radio"> <span class="label-body">Option A</span>
</label>
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. If it helps, I'm using the Skeleton framework (http://getskeleton.com/).

Comment: Link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306117/radio-buttons-and-label-to-display-in-same-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `inline-block` on the `span.label-body`, if possible. This sets the `span` in the same line as the radio button, because by default it is inline.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 0px; }
label > .label-body {
  margin-left: .5rem;
  font-weight: normal; 
}
span {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
     <input type="radio"><span class="label-body">really long label that should span more than one line because it is really long</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! Any idea how I can indent the 2nd line of wrapping text so it appears in line vertically with the first line? http://pastebin.com/P6kgifw5